# How to use login of foursqure in phonegap applications

Tags: android, cordova, foursquare

I am developing a phonegap app in android. I want to use login of foursqure like login with facebook. Can anyone please suggest a good tutorial for integrating foursquare with phonegap app?

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare supports OAuth 2.0 authentication. Similar to Facebook or any other Oauth appliacation, you register your app, redirect users to foursquare oauth login page and when they're done, foursquare gives you the access tokens which you can use later.

[Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) it explains how to connect with Foursquare. Since you're using Phonegap, you can open the Foursquare login page in InAppBrowser and get the tokens. Also take a look at [Untappd app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.untappdllc.app&hl=en) to see this in action, it implements this feature.